# Lookup table using hash on multiple (>50) columns

Tags: arrays, hash, sas

I am working with a table with more than 50 columns. I am trying to replace the value of multiple columns using a lookup table.

`Table`:

```
data have;
infile datalines delimiter=",";
input ID $1. SUB_ID :$2. COUNTRY :$2. A $1. B $1.;
datalines;
1,A,FR,A,B
2,B,CH,,B
3,C,DE,B,A
4,D,CZ,,B
5,E,GE,A,
6,F,EN,B,
7,G,US,,A
;
run;
```

`Lookup table`:

```
data lookup;
infile datalines delimiter=",";
input value_before $1. value_after :$2.;
datalines;
A,1
B,2
C,3
;
run;
```

`Actual code`:

```
data want;
  if 0 then set lookup;
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash lookup(dataset:'lookup');
    lookup.defineKey('value_before');
    lookup.defineData('value_after');
    lookup.defineDone();
  end;

  set have;
  if (lookup.find(key:A) = 0) then 
    A = value_after;
 if (lookup.find(key:B) = 0) then 
    B = value_after;
/* ... */
/* if (lookup.find(key:Z) = 0) then 
    Z = value_after; */


drop value_before value_after;
run;
```

I guess this code would do the job if I would hardcode the 50 columns.
I wonder if there is a way to "apply" the hash.find() to all variables except the first three (`ID, SUB_ID and Country`) (maybe by indexing ?) without having to hardcode them or to use macros. For the sake of example I only computed 2 variables to replace the value (A and B) but there are more than 50 (with really different names and no pattern like `var1,var2,...,varn`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, I like to use `proc sql` and the dictionary table to fill in the column names for me to create an array. The below code will pull the variable names from `dictionary.columns` and save them as space-delimited into the macro variable `varnames`. We can feed this into an array and then use array logic to do the rest.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select name
    into :varnames separated by ' '
    from dictionary.columns
    where     libname = 'WORK'
          AND memname = 'HAVE'
          AND name NOT IN('ID', 'SUB_ID', 'COUNTRY')
    ;
quit;

data want;
  if 0 then set lookup;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash lookup(dataset:'lookup');
    lookup.defineKey('value_before');
    lookup.defineData('value_after');
    lookup.defineDone();
  end;

  set have;

  array vars[*] &varnames.;

  do i = 1 to dim(vars);
      if lookup.Find(key:vars[i])=0 then vars[i] = value_after;
  end;

  drop value_before value_after i;
run;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for. However I think you meant `if(lookup.Find(key:vars[i])=0)`. Thank you !

Comment: Yep! Absolutely right. Looks like someone fixed it!